# MYSQL_DUMP export database

Tags: mysql

Trying to export database from MAMP server.  I tried commands:

```
# mysql_dump -u root -proot db_name > db_name.sql

# Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_dump -u root -proot db_name > db_name.sql
```

with and without the # sign.

all i get is a file with nothing in it.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Madbreaks At least he changed it from `root/<no password>` :)

Comment: what happens when you simply do `mysql -u root -proot`?

Comment: @madbreaks please keep your sarcasm to yourself...it is irrelevant what the u/p is set to...i ought to report that

Comment: You're right. Yes, you can always flag comments you feel are inappropriate, etc.

Comment: @mike brant error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: @user1753012 Your problem then is that you a plain not able to connect to MySQL via the means you are trying to do. It is not a problem with mysqldump.

Answer (score 0):

mysqldump -u root -proot **yourdatabase** > export.sql works fine

Comment: where to put the original database file?

Comment: where you wish , this command exports it to where the mysql program is installed , check where you have installed your mysql server and look into the bin folder

Comment: no, i mean how does that command reference my database file to export...??

Comment: changed my answer to reflect the proper syntax, i mean that after user and pass you can specify your database, without the database it would export the whole server